# Is there a way to tag a release and keep its code separate from future versions?

Tags: git, github

We just completed version 1 of our software. It will be our first release.

Our process up until now has been developers working on their own branch, and then merging to stable master after QA has approved the branch.

So now I want to release version 1, and I hope to do a monthly patch after this, and perhaps a larger release every 6 months.

I don't know how to handle master now.

I ideally want something like this:

Master is tagged as version 1, and I can return to this anytime. (Is this just create a new branch from master now and call it version 1?)

Developers can start working on new fixes or features, and their code gets merged to master when it's stable, so it's business as usual.

The 1.1 patch is released next month, and master is tagged a 1.1 at this point.

And the cycle continues.

Is there a best practice for this?

Thanks.

Comment: If developers don't continue development based on the release, what *should* they continue their development based on? Many projects do something like this, where they have a `develop ` branch and `release/*` branches, and merge back and forth between them only under specific conditions. See this article for one commonly-adopted workflow: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model

Comment: A tag in Git is just a commit, so you should be able to just checkout a given tag at a later time and create a branch from there should the need arise.

Comment: I am not sure I have completely understood your question, I suppose you want developers continue their work based on the release. Anyway, I thin you should take a look at git tagging mechanism : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You ask if there's a best practice for "this". Yes, it's "this", the process you already described. Do you see any problems with it? Do you need to go back and release a patch for version 1 that *doesn't* contain everything in master? Is this what this is about?